# what does “go-to destination” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Recently I read this phrase in a sentence .I don't understand :

> Its infinity "skypool" is now the **go-to destination** for starlets who wish to splash around in bikinis for the cameras.

here is the link of the whole article ([The Economist](http://www.economist.com/node/18231454))

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

[*go-to*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go-to) means

1. Desired; desirable; of choice *Cheesecake is my go-to food whenever I feel down.*
2. Reliable; likely to perform in difficult circumstances. *Smith is your go-to person if you want lasting results.*

It's rather a confusing adjective to use in front of *destination*, which means, of course, somewhere you go.

Answer (score 0):

The expression means *fashionable, popular, modish, desirable, trendy, all-the-rage*. That's to say that it's the place for aspiring celebrities to be noticed.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-to